# Worklight/MobileFirst Application Temp and Working Directories for Studio, clearing

Tags: java, eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

With the Worklight/MobileFirst Studio application development for local development, I see many temporary or working files.  My main issue, I may develop Java code for the server side used by an adapter and I assume that is pushed to the war file.  But I sometimes don't see the change reflected.  And sometimes I am working with the desktopbrowser/common web-application and I don't see those changes reflected.  I may do a clean and build-all and Build All Environments.

I finally just scanned my entire Mac hard drive for those App-common and App-desktopbrowser files and found several.  When I delete all of these, it looks like the working directory or cache issue is cleared up.  I assume these are used internally and not documented.  But I was curious if there is a clean way to delete these?  Also, this is an older version of Worklight, will the same issue exist with future release?  But at least I commented on directories you may not know about.

Here are the file paths that have a war file or wlapp file.  Deleting these fixes my caching issue but is there a better way?

My version of Worklight:  6.2.0.01.20150430-1522

berlins-imac$ echo $TMPDIR
/var/folders/dl/abcgq/T/

Delete the wlPreview and wlBuildResources

There are cached files here:

/Users/user/Documents/workspace62LunaNewNew4/WorklightServerConfig/servers/worklight/workarea/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles

rm -Rvf ./75/data/temp/default_node/SMF_WebContainer/MyApp/MyApp/widget-resources/MyApp-common-c2713f1cefc5f5f35bec867386f2344632197fcf

cd /Users/ap123User/Documents/workspace62LunaNewNew4/WorklightServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/myApp*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely delete these folders from the TMP folder in any way you'd like.
They get re-generated everytime you open Eclipse (with Studio installed). At least that's the case in newer releases of the product.

Comment: OK Thanks, I wish I knew about them beforehand and are there any other cached or working directories out there.